# PowerShellでコマンドプロンプトの DIR /D /OGN のような表示はできるか？

Tags: windows, powershell, コマンドプロンプト

コマンドプロンプトで`DIR /D /OGN`を実行すると、例えば以下のように、

- フォルダは角括弧で囲まれ、
- フォルダとファイルが別々に名前でソートされ、
- 縦向きの複数カラム表示で、

表示されます。

```
>dir /d /ogn
（中略）
[.]                        [Saved Games]
[..]                       [Searches]
[Contacts]                 [Tracing]
[Desktop]                  [Videos]
[Documents]                [Virtual Machines]
[Downloads]                .viminfo
[Favorites]                _gvimrc
[Links]                    _netrc
[Music]                    _vimrc
[OneDrive]                 textfile.txt
[Pictures]
```

PowerShellでこれと同じように表示させることは可能でしょうか？

一応、`Get-ChildItem | Format-Wide -AutoSize Name`で似たような表示をさせることはできましたが、下のように、

- フォルダとファイルの区別がつかない
- 複数カラム化はできているものの配置順が縦向きではなく、左から右に並べられている

ので見にくいです。

```
Contacts            Desktop             Documents
Downloads           Favorites           Links
Music               OneDrive            Pictures
Saved Games         Searches            Tracing
Videos              Virtual Machines    .viminfo
_gvimrc             _netrc              _vimrc
textfile.txt
```

Comment: `cmd /C dir /D /OGN` ではどうですか？ 個人的には既にあるものが利用できるのなら新しく作る必要は無いと思います。

Comment: なるほど！！　盲点でした！
できればPowerShellの機能でなんとかしたいところですが、無理or大変そうだったらそうすることにします。

Comment: ムリではないでしょうけど、結構な量のコード（多分ワンライナーではムリ）を書かないといけなくなると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

結局、BLUEPIXYさんのコメントの通り、

```
cmd /C dir /D /OGN
```

を実行する関数を作って利用することにしました。